# Is it possible to define a yacc grammar rule that does not require an explicit delimiter only when reaching end of input?

Tags: yacc, lex

As an exercise in learning lex and yacc, I wrote a simple parser for test cases with single-integer inputs where the input is delimited by a single line containing `##`.

```
1
##
5
##
21
##
```

This already works, but I would like to make a modification to the grammar so that the delimiter `##` is optional for the **last test case only**.

My thinking is that if there was some magic token I can put in the rule to indicate "end of input", then I could write something like this:

```
| test_case_suite test_case <magic_end_of_input> {
  add_case($2);
}
```

Unfortunately, my searches haven't turned up anything like this.

**Is it possible to define this kind of grammar in yacc?**

---

Here is my `lex` input:

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
[0-9]+ {
yylval.i = atoi(yytext);
return INTEGER;
}
^##$ {
return TERMINATOR;
}
%%
int yywrap(void) {
return 1;
}
```

Here is my `yacc` grammar:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *);

struct TestCase {
  int n;
};

struct Node {
  struct TestCase* test_case;
  struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* root = NULL;
void add_case(struct TestCase* test_case) {
  struct Node* new_root = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  new_root->test_case = test_case;
  new_root->next = root;
  root = new_root;
}

%}
%union {
int i;
struct TestCase* tcPtr;
};
%token <i> INTEGER
%token TERMINATOR
%type <tcPtr> test_case
%%
test_case_suite:
test_case_suite test_case TERMINATOR {
  add_case($2);
}
| test_case_suite test_case {
  add_case($2);
}
|
;
test_case:
INTEGER {
  struct TestCase* test_case = malloc(sizeof(struct TestCase));
  test_case->n = $1;
  $$ = test_case;
}
%%
void yyerror(char *s) {
  fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", s);
}
int main(void) {
yyparse();
struct Node* cur = root;
while (cur != NULL) {
  printf("n = %d\n", cur->test_case->n);
  cur = cur->next;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is doable with a two-step approach.

1. Modify `test_case_suite` to require `TERMINATOR` before adding a new test case.
2. Add an extra layer `input` that wraps a `test_case_suite` and optionally allows a terminating `TERMINATOR`.

Here's the final yacc file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "soup_servings.h"
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *);
void add_case(struct TestCase* test_case);

%}
%union {
int i;
struct TestCase* tcPtr;
};
%token <i> INTEGER
%token TERMINATOR
%type <tcPtr> test_case
%%
input:
test_case_suite
| test_case_suite TERMINATOR;
test_case_suite:
test_case_suite TERMINATOR test_case {
  add_case($3);
}
| test_case {
  add_case($1);
}
|
;
test_case:
INTEGER {
  struct TestCase* test_case = malloc(sizeof(struct TestCase));
  test_case->n = $1;
  $$ = test_case;
}
%%
void yyerror(char *s) {
  fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", s);
}

struct Node* root = NULL;
void add_case(struct TestCase* test_case) {
  struct Node* new_root = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  new_root->test_case = test_case;
  new_root->next = root;
  root = new_root;
}
```